# How can I get all the JS files name

Tags: tapestry

How can I get all JS files name of my application ?

I tested :

```
@Inject
private ClientInfrastructure javascriptStack;

void onActivate(){
    mesJavaScripts=javascriptStack.getJavascriptStack();

    for(Asset javascript : mesJavaScripts){
      System.out.println(javascript.toString());
    }
}
```

But I do not have all the JS. Do I use the good service ?

Thanks

Comment: In fact, I just got the "basic" js file. How can i get the stack, with the js added with the @IncludeJavaScriptLibrary annotation for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't follow the need here; the question of whether necessary JS files are included in the response is an *integration test* issue; you can determine this using PageTester (by walking the returned DOM) or in Selenium (again, by walking the client DOM).

In fact, ideally (and this is difficult) you could write tests, in Selenium, that only pass if the necessary JS is in place.

Given that Tapestry will, in production mode, aggregate your scripts together into JS stacks (and that may change in some way in 5.3) you are testing *state* rather than *behavior*.  Always test *behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

This way seems to work, although it relies on some internals that could change and it may slow things down a bit. Depending on your need, you might want to filter that based on a request parameter set in the pages you care about (add RequestGlobals as a parameter and use set/getAttribute).

A better way may be to provide your own DocumentLinker that captures the scripts as they get added.

Add this to your AppModule:

```
public void contributeMarkupRenderer(OrderedConfiguration<MarkupRendererFilter> configuration, final Environment environment, final RequestGlobals request) {
  MarkupRendererFilter getScripts = new MarkupRendererFilter() {
    public void renderMarkup(MarkupWriter writer, MarkupRenderer renderer) {
      DocumentLinker dl = environment.peek(DocumentLinker.class);
      renderer.renderMarkup(writer);
      try {
        List<String> scripts = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("scripts");
        if (scripts != null) {
          scripts.clear();
          Field f = dl.getClass().getDeclaredField("scripts");
          f.setAccessible(true);
          scripts.addAll((List<String>)f.get(dl));
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
  };
  configuration.add("getScripts", getScripts, "after:DefaultValidationDecorator");
}
```

In your test:

```
request.setAttribute("scripts", new ArrayList<String>());
```

execute the page

```
assert request.getAttribute("scripts").contains(path_to_script_you_want_to_check);
```

You might have to change either side to strip off the extra path information that Tapestry adds.

Comment: I just want in my TestNG tests, check if the good js file is included.

Comment: @Gillespie59: Well, now that Brian has effectively written the code for you, what could stop you?

Comment: I modified the answer to show you how you could use it in your tests. It assumes you can set a request attribute in your test to indicate you care about the scripts.